# No speed-up obtained by using compiler::cmpfun in R function to calculate iterative logic (func(i) depends on func(i - 1))

Tags: r, jit

I have a function to iteratively calculate the result at time-step `i + 1` given the result at time-step `i`.

It's my understanding that this cannot be expressed in the form of a vectorized operation. I have a non-vectorized custom function, that I am calling using the `dplyr` `group_map` function (since I need to apply this by group).

I was hoping that my custom function + compiler would result in significant faster execution. I find, instead, that there is no difference in run time.

The function I have so far is like this:

```
predict_iterative = function(initial_state, type, constant_input_1, 
                             constant_input_2, time_series_input) {
  # Error check
  if(any(length(initial_state) != 1, length(type) != 1, 
         length(constant_input_1) != 1, length(constant_input_2) != 1)) {
    stop("All args except time_series_input must be 1D")
  }
  if(any(type %in% c("type1", "type2"))) {
    stop("Only type1 or type2 allowed for arg type")
  }
  
  # Pre-allocate vectors
  predicted_response = rep(0, length(time_series_input))         # same length as time_series
  updated_state = rep(initial_state, length(time_series_input))  # same length as time_series
  temp = 0                                                       # scalar temp used in calc
  constant_input_2_unit_change = constant_input_2 * 2.54         # pre-calculate scalar constant
  
  # Edge-case: Only 1 time-step (Don't compute next time-step)
  if(length(time_series_input) == 1) {
    predicted_response = time_series_input * updated_state

    return(tibble(predicted_response, updated_state))
  }
  
  # Keep branches outside of loop
  if(type == "type1") {
    for(i in seq(1, length(time_series_input) - 1)) {
      predicted_response[i] = time_series_input[i] * updated_state[i]
      temp = constant_input_1 - updated_state[i] * constant_input_2_unit_change
      
      # The iterative roadblock
      updated_state[i + 1] = updated_state[i] - predicted_response[i] - temp
    }
    # Last time-step (loop ran till 2nd last time-step)
    predicted_response[i + 1] = time_series_input[i + 1] * updated_state[i + 1]
  } else {
    # Same as the if-branch, but with minor detail changes
  }

  return(tibble(predicted_response, updated_state))
}
```

Based on my efforts (pre-allocating vectors, keeping dimensions of input variables to the minimum needed, and avoiding branches in loop), the performance has improved by a factor of 2.25x.

I then turned to the `compiler` package.

compiler code using `cmpfun`:

```
enableJIT(3)
predict_iterative_compiled = cmpfun(predict_iterative)  # printing body shows the "bytecode", so it is compiled

# This runs in the same time it took without cmpfun
df %>% 
  group_by(grouping) %>% 
  group_map(function(df, g) {
    initial_state = df[[1, "initial_state"]]
    type = df[[1, "type"]]
    constant_input_1 = df[[1, "constant_input_1"]]
    constant_input_2 = df[[1, "constant_input_2"]]
    time_series_input = df$time_series_input
    predict_iterative_compiled(initial_state, type, constant_input_1, 
                               constant_input_2, time_series_input)
  }) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

What's missing here? How can I get faster execution with minimal dev effort?

Comment: JIT is already enabled by default. One easy way to improve speed is to apply some multithreading.

Comment: @thc What package would you recommend I look into? My data-frame on which I want to do group_map is fairly large, sitting at 70% of system RAM, so I am nervous of anything that requires copies to be made.

Comment: parallel::mclapply or the future.apply package could work.

Comment: @thc I should mention I am on a Windows system with fairly restrictive IT policies. mclapply probably won't work due to the Windows forking issue.

Comment: In that case multithreading based on sockets should still work (parallel::parLapply or future.apply would still work). Make sure your predict_iterative function is self contained (so you don't have to export large global variables).